# Spring's @ComponentScan excludeFilters multiple filters

Tags: spring-boot

I need to exclude multiple patterns of packages from:

```
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = "com.data",
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
        type = FilterType.REGEX,
        pattern = "package.*"
    )
)
```

I am using spring boot LATEST.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`excludeFilters` takes an array

```
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = "com.example",
    excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(...),
        @ComponentScan.Filter(...),
        @ComponentScan.Filter(...),
    }
)
```